# Is MADV_DONTNEED immediately after mmap() doing anything useful?

Tags: linux, mmap

I'm creating a software that uses a large `mmap()`'d anonymous memory block, most of which is unused -- it's there for future expansion. I'm currently allocating it with `mmap()`, and then telling the operating system kernel that I don't actually need the allocated pages with `madvise(ptr, bytes, MADV_DONTNEED)`.

Is there any benefit to doing this `madvise()` call? Can I just allocate the memory using `mmap()`?

I already found the core files become quite big with lots of `mmap()'d` memory so I handle `SIGSEGV` and few other signals and `munmap()` the portion I don't want to leave to the core file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No `MADV_DONTNEED` has no effect if used immediately after `mmap`.

To avoid core dump bloat on Linux 3.4 and later you could use `madvise` with `MADV_DONTDUMP`.